# Where and how to download MySQL source code?

Tags: mysql

I want to download MySQL source code. Then i also want to install it and compile it within my computer on Linux environment. How can i do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

There are few good reasons to do this other than applying patches or for learning's sake. If you are installing this on anything other than your personal machine consider using your distribution's package manager. From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-installation.html)  for these [supported platforms](http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html):

> Before you proceed with an installation from source, check whether Oracle produces a precompiled binary distribution for your platform and whether it works for you. We put a great deal of effort into ensuring that our binaries are built with the best possible options for optimal performance.

- Verify that your system satisfies the tool requirements listed at [Section 2.8, “Installing MySQL from Source”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-installation.html).
- Obtain a distribution file using the instructions in [Section 2.1.2, “How to Get MySQL”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-mysql.html).
- Configure, build, and install the distribution: the [exact steps required](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing-source-distribution.html) after installing the correct tools and downloading the source:

.

```
# Preconfiguration setup
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql
# Beginning of source-build specific instructions
shell> tar zxvf mysql-VERSION.tar.gz
shell> cd mysql-VERSION
shell> cmake .
shell> make
shell> make install
# End of source-build specific instructions
# Postinstallation setup
shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql data
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
# Next command is optional
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

- Perform postinstallation procedures using the instructions in [Section 2.9, “Postinstallation Setup and Testing”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/postinstallation.html).

You don't specify OS, so:

- [How to Build MySQL 5.5 from Source Code on Windows](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=689)
- [Detailed instructions for compiling MySQL Server from source code on Linux](http://howtolamp.com/lamp/mysql/5.6/installing/)